# call partial view into div via ajax and include there js and css files

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

hi I want to call a partial view into a dive in my primary layout with ajax (no refresh page)

my code is

```
var trigger = $('.sidebarMenuWrapper ul li a'), container = $('#container');
trigger.on('click', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var $this = $(this), target = $this.attr('href');       
       $.ajax({
           url: target,
           type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'html',
           async: false,
           success: function (result) {
               $('#container').html(result);
           }
       });

   });
```

the pages loaded correctly into the container div but it not take the included js and css file called in layout

for exemple I have a datatables in this partial view 
when it loaded via ajax it will not display

thank for help

Comment: A partial view does not have a layout, and partial views should not contain scripts. Just move the scripts and style sheets into the main view (and attach the plug in to the relevant element after you update the DOM)

Comment: how can i attache the plug ?

Comment: The same way you would do it in a main view - `$(someElement).DataTable({ ... });` - just do it in the ajax success callback after `$('#container').html(result);`